# How can I troubleshoot the differences between two pandas dataframes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes that don't look equals, but I can't find any difference at all.
I simplified down to two dataframes with only one column called "Name"

```py
print("are df equals? ", a_dev.equals(a_train))
m=a_dev.merge(a_train,on="Name",how="outer",indicator=True)
diff=m[m["_merge"]!="both"]
len(diff.index)
a_dev.shape
a_train.shape
a_dev.columns
a_train.columns
```

I get as result:

```
are df equals?  False
0
(145,1)
(145,1)
Index(['Name'], dtype='object')
Index(['Name'], dtype='object')
```

Basically, the _merge columns it's always "both"

I've tried everything I found on SO.
Concat, and drop duplicates. Left join. .isin and drop null.

I've written the two dataframes to excel and they looks equal.

Don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: I would perhaps try saving them as CSV and diffing with `diff` from a command prompt. Don't know if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess what you are dealing with here, but here is a reproducible example which might point you in the right direction.

The two following dataframes appear identical when printed in the terminal or displayed in a Jupyter notebook:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Supposedly, you don't have access to this instantiation step
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3, "4"], "col2": ["1", "2", "3", 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["1", "2", "3", 4], "col2": [1, 2, 3, "4"]})
```

```py
print(df1)
# Output
  col1 col2
0    1    1
1    2    2
2    3    3
3    4    4

print(df2)
# Output
  col1 col2
0    1    1
1    2    2
2    3    3
3    4    4
```

But `df1.equals(df2)` outputs `False`.

Although `df1.info()` and `df2.info()` tell otherwise:

```py
print(df1.info())
# Output
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   col1    4 non-null      object
 1   col2    4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes

print(df2.info())
# Output
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   col1    4 non-null      object
 1   col2    4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes
```

And yet:

```py
df = pd.merge(
    left=df1, right=df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer", indicator=True
)
diff = df[df["_merge"] != "both"]

print(len(diff.index))  # Output: 0
```

What happens here is that columns are all categorize as `object` type, which mixes several types that are taken into account when comparing both dataframes.

And so, if you uniformize types:

```py
print(df1.astype(str).equals(df2.astype(str)))  # Output: True
print(df1.astype(int).equals(df2.astype(int)))  # Output: True
```

You can investigate to find which values are strings instead of integers, like this:

```py
for df in [df1, df2]:
    for col in ["col1", "col2"]:
        print(f"\n{[x for x in vars().keys() if globals()[x] is df][0]}:")
        print(df.loc[df[col].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)), col])

# Output
df1:
3    4
Name: col1, dtype: object

df1:
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: col2, dtype: object

df2:
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: col1, dtype: object

df2:
3    4
Name: col2, dtype: object
```